# Display 8 images using the whole page

Tags: html, css

I have some webcams, that I'm trying to display nicely on 1 html page. This page wil be used on 2 or 3 screens (using Rpi or windows client).
All the screens have different resolutions, but I'm trying to make my view responsive to the display.

I'm trying to display it like this:

[image]

Currently I have this code:

```
    <html>
<body bgcolor=000000>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" >
<!--
function ChangeMedia(){
    var d = new Date();
    var t = d.getTime();
    document.getElementById('cam1').src = "http://10.101.4.2/image.jpg?feed=%7B66CA3FEA-7841-4486-B7D2-253EBF08E852%7D&webview&quality=100&noupsample=1/"+t;
    document.getElementById('cam2').src = "http://10.101.4.2/image.jpg?feed=%7BEB2548AA-3183-4FB9-BD5A-199887346827%7D&webview&quality=100&noupsample=2/"+t;
    document.getElementById('cam3').src = "http://10.101.4.2/image.jpg?feed=%7B6A3C56CE-F186-4205-9A62-7740207F8BEF%7D&webview&quality=100&noupsample=2/"+t;
    document.getElementById('cam4').src = "http://10.101.4.2/image.jpg?feed=%7BAB013929-4D26-4CD4-82BA-F13532D4E7CE%7D&webview&quality=100&noupsample=2/"+t;
    document.getElementById('cam5').src = "http://10.101.4.2/image.jpg?feed=%7BE9FB6FCC-0748-48A5-A679-DBD875C5A651%7D&webview&quality=100&noupsample=2/"+t;
    document.getElementById('cam6').src = "http://10.101.4.2/image.jpg?feed=%7B0E5C454A-98DC-4C16-95B9-CE3B6097B2E7%7D&webview&quality=100&noupsample=2/"+t;


}
var reloadcam = setInterval("ChangeMedia()",500);



</script>
<script type="text/javascript">



function DisplayTime(){
if (!document.all && !document.getElementById)
return
timeElement=document.getElementById? document.getElementById("curTime"): document.all.tick2
var CurrentDate=new Date()
var hours=CurrentDate.getHours()
var minutes=CurrentDate.getMinutes()
var seconds=CurrentDate.getSeconds()
if (minutes<=9) minutes="0"+minutes;
if (seconds<=9) seconds="0"+seconds;
var currentTime=hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds;
timeElement.innerHTML="<font style='font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;'>"+currentTime+"</b>"
setTimeout("DisplayTime()",1000)
}
window.onload=DisplayTime
</script>     

<center>
<img src="" alt="Loading..." name="cam" border="0" width=25% id="cam1" />
<img src="" alt="Loading..." name="cam" border="0" width=25% id="cam2" />
<img src="" alt="Loading..." name="cam" border="0" width=25% id="cam3" />
<img src="" alt="Loading..." name="cam" border="0" width=25% id="cam4" />
<img src="" alt="Loading..." name="cam" border="0" width=25% id="cam5" />
<img src="" alt="Loading..." name="cam" border="0" width=25% id="cam6" />
<img src="" alt="Loading..." name="cam" border="0" width=25% id="cam6" />

<br>
<span style="color:white" id=curTime></span>
</center>

</body>
</html>
```

Which results in this:
[image]

Now I'm wondering how I can make it work so that I get 1 pic bigger, and 3 smaller right to it, and 4 smaller below. The whole width should be used.
Should I use tables, but will I still be able to make it responsive when a smaller or 4:3 screen is used?

Extra issue is that not all images are the same size. I was thinking of cropping them a bit by using object-fit.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The simplest way would probably be to split the resolution up into the right size chunks using percentage-based calculations. Then make your divs and just make your feeds fit in each box.

Answer (score 0):

You may use Bootstrap grid, something like...

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8">Big screen</div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">Small screen</div>
                <div class="col-xs-12">Small screen</div>
                <div class="col-xs-12">Small screen</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">Small screen</div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">Small screen</div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">Small screen</div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">Small screen</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Although this may be accomplished also with table or flex mockup, up to your choice

Answer (score 0):

It's not an ideal solution but if you choose to use tables this should work:

```js
function ChangeMedia(){
    var d = new Date();
    var t = d.getTime();
    document.getElementById('cam1').src = "http://10.101.4.2/image.jpg?feed=%7B66CA3FEA-7841-4486-B7D2-253EBF08E852%7D&webview&quality=100&noupsample=1/"+t;
    document.getElementById('cam2').src = "http://10.101.4.2/image.jpg?feed=%7BEB2548AA-3183-4FB9-BD5A-199887346827%7D&webview&quality=100&noupsample=2/"+t;
    document.getElementById('cam3').src = "http://10.101.4.2/image.jpg?feed=%7B6A3C56CE-F186-4205-9A62-7740207F8BEF%7D&webview&quality=100&noupsample=2/"+t;
    document.getElementById('cam4').src = "http://10.101.4.2/image.jpg?feed=%7BAB013929-4D26-4CD4-82BA-F13532D4E7CE%7D&webview&quality=100&noupsample=2/"+t;
    document.getElementById('cam5').src = "http://10.101.4.2/image.jpg?feed=%7BE9FB6FCC-0748-48A5-A679-DBD875C5A651%7D&webview&quality=100&noupsample=2/"+t;
    document.getElementById('cam6').src = "http://10.101.4.2/image.jpg?feed=%7B0E5C454A-98DC-4C16-95B9-CE3B6097B2E7%7D&webview&quality=100&noupsample=2/"+t;


}

var reloadcam = setInterval("ChangeMedia()",500);




function DisplayTime(){
if (!document.all && !document.getElementById)
return
timeElement=document.getElementById? document.getElementById("curTime"): document.all.tick2
var CurrentDate=new Date()
var hours=CurrentDate.getHours()
var minutes=CurrentDate.getMinutes()
var seconds=CurrentDate.getSeconds()
if (minutes<=9) minutes="0"+minutes;
if (seconds<=9) seconds="0"+seconds;
var currentTime=hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds;
timeElement.innerHTML="<font style='font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;'>"+currentTime+"</b>"
setTimeout("DisplayTime()",1000)
}

window.onload=DisplayTime;
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3" colspan="2">  
<img src="" alt="Loading..." name="cam" border="0" width=25% id="cam1" />
      </td>
    <td>
<img src="" alt="Loading..." name="cam" border="0" width=25% id="cam2" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      
<img src="" alt="Loading..." name="cam" border="0" width=25% id="cam3" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
<img src="" alt="Loading..." name="cam" border="0" width=25% id="cam4" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
<img src="" alt="Loading..." name="cam" border="0" width=25% id="cam5" />
      </td>
    <td>
<img src="" alt="Loading..." name="cam" border="0" width=25% id="cam6" />
      </td>
    <td>
<img src="" alt="Loading..." name="cam" border="0" width=25% id="cam6" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

<br>
<span style="color:white" id=curTime></span>
```